# How to Capture Oracle JDBC PL/SQL Function Call's Parameter Values in WebSphere 7

Tags: java, oracle, logging, jdbc, websphere

We are placing PL/SQL function calls via Oracle JDBC driver (11.2) (using Spring JDBCTemplate* framework), and we have set **com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.*=all** in WebSphere server's logging details (Runtime), but the captured data in the `trace.log` file does not contain the actual translated PL/SQL function call nor the values of the parameters being passed to the function.

How can I achieve this logging detail? We are using SLF4j library for logging as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works regardless of what logging framework you have deployed for your application, i.e. *Log4j*, `java.util.logging`, *SLF4j*, etc.:

1. Obtain a corresponding *Oracle JDBC* driver that has been compiled with tracing code enabled (**ending with "_g.jar"**). As long as the Oracle JDBC driver's *major* version matches the underlying database's, it's best to get the *latest minor version* (in our case, 11.2.0.4.0) as it outputs additional information for each call.

   The latest diagnostic driver is going to be compatible with the older versions of your *Oracle* database. You can obtain them from [*Oracle*'s website here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html).
2. If you have used a **WebSphere variable** (i.e. `Oracle JDBC Driver`) to specify the location of *Oracle JDBC* driver, place the diagnostic *JDBC* driver in the same folder as the regular driver (for ease of tracking). Nonetheless, you can place it anywhere on the file system.
3. Make sure the WebSphere user that starts up the server has proper file system permission to access the driver, i.e. *ojdbc6_g.jar*.
4. From *WebSphere Admin Console*, change the *JDBC* provider to point to the new driver:

   - Expand **Resources**
   - Expand **JDBC**
   - Select **JDBC providers**
   - Select "**Oracle JDBC Driver**" (or whatever Java Database Connectivity provider has been named on the server)
   - Alter the "**Class path**" from "**${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6.jar**" to "**${ORACLE_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH}/ojdbc6_g.jar**"
   - Click **Apply**
5. To set the trace logging level:

   - Expand **Servers**
   - Expand **Server Types**
   - Click **WebSphere application servers**
   - Select the target server
   - Scroll down to "**Troubleshooting**" sub-section
   - Select "**Change Log Detail Levels**"
   - Switch to **Runtime** tab
   - Change the Components from "***=info**" to "***=info: oracle.jdbc.*=all**" (without double quotations)
   - Click **Apply**
   - Note the logging level can be altered at runtime, i.e. rather than "**all**", you can supply "**fine**", "**finer**", or "**finest**". The list of what each [logging level entails to is here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rtrb_loglevels.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F1-16-5-541).
6. Locate the server logging folder:

   - Repeat 5a to 5e
   - Select "**Logging and tracing**"
   - Select "**Diagnostic Trace**"
   - Under "**General Properties/Trace Output**" section, File Name should provide the name of the trace file (the default is **${SERVER_LOG_ROOT}/trace.log**). Note that the trace log file could be in rolling/rotating mode based on size or date
7. Restart the WebSphere server
8. Execute a code that invokes a *PL/SQL* function call
9. *WebSphere* should capture all the detail *JDBC* calls in `trace.log` file now, i.e. calling `schema_user.plsql_package.procedure()` with three parameters and values of `parameter 1`, `parameter 2`, and `parameter 3`, would result in (`{call ...}` is how I'm calling stored procedures from *Spring*'s `JdbcTemplate*`, but you can see how at the low level, Oracle driver translates it into a *PL/SQL* anonymous block call):

```html
...

[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Enter: 1, "parameter 1", 2
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Public Enter: 1, "parameter 1"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 1, "parameter 1", 2
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 1, "parameter 1", 2, 0
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 1, "parameter 1", 2, 0
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 1, oracle.sql.NUMBER@42764276
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.0409ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.1926ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.2515ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.3107ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Exit [0.4817ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Exit [0.5556ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Enter: 2, "parameter 2"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Public Enter: 2, "parameter 2"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 2, "parameter 2"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 2, "parameter 2"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.0049ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.0691ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Exit [0.1276ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Exit [0.2008ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Enter: 3, "parameter 3"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Public Enter: 3, "parameter 3"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 3, "parameter 3"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   263D263D Enter: 3, "parameter 3"
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.0036ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        <   263D263D Exit [0.0549ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        1   263D263D Exit [0.1094ms]
[1/20/15 10:22:14:431 EDT] 00000020 driver        Z   263D263D Exit [0.161ms]

...

[1/20/15 10:22:14:433 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   32B732B7 Enter: "

{call schema_user.plsql_package.procedure(
param_1 => :param_1,
param_2 => :param_2,
param_3 => :param_3)}"

...

[1/20/15 10:22:14:434 EDT] 00000020 driver        2   32B732B7 Return: 

BEGIN schema_user.plsql_package.procedure(
param_1 => :param_1,
param_2 => :param_2,
param_3 => :param_3); END;

...
```

The *Oracle JDBC* driver does perform caching of stored procedure calls made by the applications. Consequently, after the first invocation, the log file does not capture all the needed information that it does on the first try -- the scope of captured information is not going to be as comprehensive as the first invocation. Moreover, the trace logging is detailed enough that can make the parsing the interested sections unwieldy.

Therefore, in order to purge the cached stored procedure calls by the driver after the first invocation, follow the instructions below:

1. Log-in to WebSphere Admin Console (Integrated Solutions Console)
2. Navigate to **Resources** -> **JDBC**  -> **Data sources**
3. Check an appropriate data source box which handles procedure calls, if any different
4. Click the "**Manage state...**" button on the top of the grid table
5. On "**JCA lifecycle management**" page, check box the same resource
6. Click the "**Purge**" button

Also, if you are running/testing your *WebSphere* in the *Windows* environment, you can use [SnakeTail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/) tool to `tail` (like *Unix/Linux* systems) `trace.log` file (quite fast and responsive with large buffer size).